# Having Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] while filtering nested ng-repeats

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to filter nested ng-repeats while using a custom filter recommended by official angularjs error helper.

On my local machine, it didn't filter anything as well as throw an error in console:

```
Error: $rootScope:infdig
Infinite $digest Loop
```

I have attached a plunker demo of this issue.

In plunker, the filtering is working fine but still the error is appearing in console.

**HTML:**

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <h1>Hello Vehicles!</h1>
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input type="text" class="filter-vehicles-input" id="filter_vehicles" name="filter_vehicles" value="" placeholder="Search Vehicles" ng-model="filter_vehicles">

    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="(key, vModel) in vehiclesByModel | customFilter: filter_vehicles">
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="model_id" value="{{key}}" ng-click="selectAllTrucks($event)">
          <strong>{{ key | uppercase }}</strong>
        </div>
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="vehicle in vModel track by $index">
            <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle_id" value="{{vehicle.TruckID}}" ng-model="selectedVehicleIds[vehicle.TruckID]"> {{ vehicle.licensePlate + ' (' +vehicle.identifier+ ')' | uppercase }}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

**JS:**

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.vehiclesByModel = {
      "Toyota": [{
        "vehicleID": "102",
        "licensePlate": "XYZ123",
        "identifier": "Corolla"
      }, {
        "vehicleID": "103",
        "licensePlate": "XYZ124",
        "identifier": "Corolla Advanced"
      }],
      "Honda": [{
        "vehicleID": "104",
        "licensePlate": "XYZ1254",
        "identifier": "City"
      }, {
        "vehicleID": "105",
        "licensePlate": "XYZ124ghf",
        "identifier": "Civic"
      }]
    };


  }).filter('customFilter', function() {
    return function(input, search) {
      if (!input) return input;
      if (!search) return input;
      var expected = ('' + search).toLowerCase();
      var result = {};
      angular.forEach(input, function(value, key) {
        result[key] = {};
        angular.forEach(value, function(v, k) {
          var actual = ('' + v.identifier).toLowerCase();
          var actual2 = ('' + v.licensePlate).toLowerCase();
          if (actual.indexOf(expected) !== -1 || actual2.indexOf(expected) !== -1) {
            result[key][k] = v;
          }
        });
      });
      return result;
    };
  });
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/b0oghi75e5S0W8pnmAW8?p=preview